# Крыльцо, навес, кронштейн

Tags: лексика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы узнать у вас об изображенном на картинке. Является ли это "крыльцом"? Можно ли назвать крышу над дверью навесом или козырьком? Имеет ли она специальное название? А то, на чем она укреплена - кронштейн?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это навес, который держится с помощью кронштейна. Кронштейн применяется для крепления козырьков, навесов, балконов на вертикальной плоскости. Козырёк короче навеса.